# ¿Como sumo los datos que contiene un campo de una tabla?

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos, necesito generar un reporte diario de ingresos, la consulta no es mi problema porque tendría que seleccionar los montos de la tabla pagos donde la fecha de pago sea hoy. Mi problema es que para hacer ese reporte de ingresos diarios tengo que sumar todos los montos que cumplan con esa condición. Estas son las tablas donde estan esos montos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De estas dos tablas me tengo que traer esos montos, lo que no se es como sumar todos los montos donde la fecha de pago sea hoy. Gracias a quien me oriente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", 'nombre_bd');
$montoshoy;
if (!$conn) {
    die("Conexion con MySQL invalida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
  echo "Conexion con MySQL correcta";
}

    $sql = "SELECT monto FROM tabla where fecha=NOW()";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $montoshoy+=intval($row['monto']);
}
}
$conn->close();
```

El código sería algo así. La única duda es si el NOW() funcionaría sino debería ser un date(y-m-d) de PHP. Saludos.

Comment: Juanjo me ha servido tu respuesta gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar la función de agregación `SUM` para obtener el monto total, y mediante `CURDATE` (que devuelve la fecha actual en formato `YYY-MM-DD`) filtrar el resultado para que solo sume los pagos del día.

```
SELECT SUM(monto) FROM pago_estudiantes WHERE fecha_del_pago_hecho = CURDATE();
```

Además, en caso de ser necesario podes utilizar la función `DATE_FORMAT` para dar formato a una fecha según la máscara especificada.

```
SELECT SUM(monto) FROM pago_estudiantes
WHERE fecha_del_pago_hecho = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%d-%m-%y");
```

Comment: Matias no hay forma de cambiar el formato del CURDATE? porque las fechas las tengo guardadas DD-MM-YY

Comment: @AlejoMendoza Edité la respuesta, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Matias si funciono tu respuesta, aunque lo he hecho con PHP. Gracias igualmente